# Freezable.IsFrozen and DependencyObject.IsSealed

Tags: c#, .net

What is the difference between those two? Aren't they semantically equivalent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. `Freezable.IsFrozen` can be toggled (one time) from outside the class by calling the `Freeze()` method, `DependencyObject.IsSealed` is read-only and its value can only be set internally by the class itself.

Comment: No, once set to true, a value of a Freezable.IsFrozen cannot be changed : " This effectively is a one-time operation to change the IsFrozen property from the initial default false state to the true state. There is no available means to set the value back to false ..."